# How to enable ssh proxy every time I resume desktop

Tags: startup, ssh

I start ssh proxy by a command similar to the following when I login to the desktop.

```
ssh -N awsproxy.vpc
```

Also, I need to type this every single time I resume my desktop from sleep mode. Can you tell me any automated way to switch ssh proxy on if you know, please?

Answer (score 1):

[SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de) will let you run shell scripts when the computer goes to sleep and wakes up.

There are step-by-step instructions at http://theglenbot.com/sleep-and-wake-scripting-osx/ but the premise is pretty simple, there's one script which runs when the computer is going to sleep, and another one which runs when it is waking up.

However, I would also recommend checking out [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) which can trigger events off system wake and a *lot* of other criteria, and it's a lot easier and more fun to use.